# Дочерние процессы

Tags: linux, c

Здравствуйте.
Прощу помощи в решении задачи.

**Задание:**

> Родительский процесс создает два дочерних.
>   Каждый из них печатает свой идентификатор процесса, после чего родительский процесс выводит "Hello world".
>   Используемые функции:
>   fork(), wait(), exit().

Мой код:

```
    pid_t p1, p2;
    int status1, status2;
    switch (p1 = fork())
    {
        case -1:
            perror("Error fork");
            return 1;
        case 0:
            printf("Child,  pid=%d\n",  getpid());

    }
    switch (p2 = fork())
    {
        case -1:
            perror("Error fork");
            return 1;
        case 0:
            printf("Child,  pid=%d\n",  getpid());
    }
    waitpid(p1, &status1, 0);
    waitpid(p2, &status2, 0);
    printf("Hello World");
```

На выходе:

> 1. Child, pid=5629
> 2. Child, pid=5630
> 3. Hello WorldChild, pid=5631
> 4. Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldPress  to close this window...

Укажите на ошибку пожалуйста.

Comment: Конкретное решение уже отметили. Общая ошибка была в понимании логики fork. Сначала дважды форкнулась "голова", затем форкнулась первая копия, так как отработав она продолжила делать то же, что и родительский процесс. Затем все четыре (голова + дети) полученных процесса с радостью сообщили - "привет мир".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас после того как форкнули процесс, сначала выполняется

```
printf("Child,  pid=%d\n",  getpid());
```

а затем продолжается оставшаяся часть программы (в том числе вывод "Hello, World"). Поставьте после printf(..); выход из программы:

```
printf("Child,  pid=%d\n",  getpid());
exit(0);
```

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо.